# Did the ampersand behavior change in Powershell 3.0?

Tags: powershell, nuget, powershell-3.0, chocolatey

I've gotten the following error when installing [windirstat](http://windirstat.info/) and [ilmerge](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/people/mbarnett/ilmerge.aspx) on [Chocolatey](http://chocolatey.org/). I'm suspicious that ampersand behavior changed in PowerShell 3.0.

```
Running powershell -NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy unrestricted -Command "& import-module -name  'C:\NuGet\chocolateyInstall\helpers\chocolateyInstaller.psm1'; & 'C:\NuGet\lib\ilmerge.2.10.526.4\tools\chocolateyInstall.ps1'". This may take awhile and permissions may need to be elevated, depending on the package.
ilmerge did not finish successfully. Boo to the chocolatey gods!
-----------------------
[ERROR] The expression after '&' in a pipeline element produced an invalid object. It must result in a command name, script block or Command
Info object.
-----------------------
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem was not ampersand behavior I had to replace `$oc = Get-Command 'Write-Host' | ?{$_.ModuleName -eq 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility'}` with `$oc = Get-Command 'Write-Host' -Module 'Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility'` as well as make a similar replacement for a Write-Error wrapper.

Answer (score 2):

How about starting PowerShell with the -version 1.0 or 2.0 parameter?  Then run the above command and see if there is any difference.

At the commandline

PowerShell -version 2.0